# problems with apples vDSP examples

Tags: c, macos, linker, vdsp

I'm having problems with apples [examples](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/SampleCode/SampleCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH205-47850) for vDSP. I tried all of them but i need the convolution sample in the end.
I can't even get it through the linker:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_conv", referenced from:
      _ConvTiming in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Is the error message (no matter what architecture i build for or).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the Accelerate framework in the build.